# Download counter

Tags: php, jquery

Here's one to think about...

I've created a jQuery & PHP procedure that allows me to count the amount of times a file has been downloaded.

**update!**

the **new** jQuery code after reading your answers:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.download', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var act = 'downloaded';

    request = $.ajax({
        url: "view/jquery/player.doitem.php",
        type: "post",
        data: { id : id, act : act },
        dataType: "json"
    });
    request.done(function(data) {
        window.location(data.download);
    });
});
```

the **new** PHP code:

```
$id = intval($_POST['id']);
$act = $_POST['act'];

$sql = "update media set " . $act . "=" . $act . "+1 where id='" . $id . "' limit 1";
$main->query($sql);

$sql = "select * from media where id='" . $id . "' limit 1";
$result = $main->query($sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$title = $row['title'];
$srctype = $row['source_type'];
$filename = $row['filename'];
$srcuri = $main->getSrcUri($srctype, $filename);
$download = $main->getSiteConfig("media_ext_src") . "/" . $main->getSiteConfig("media_ext_dir") . "/download.php?file=" . $filename;

$data = array("srcuri" => $srcuri, "title" => $title, "download" => $download);
$data = json_encode($data);

echo $data;
```

The download counter works properly, every time the download link is clicked the PHP script is fired and the database is updated.
But it doesn't start the actual download. I thought using `window.location()` would trigger the browser to start the download, but it doesn't.

How can I tell jQuery to download the file using the data returned from the PHP script?

Comment: Can't you just do `update media set downloaded=downloaded+1 where id='.intval($_POST['id']).'`? That way, no race conditions!

Comment: The problem is that following the link reloads the page and cancels any Javascript that was running, so the AJAX call is cancelled.

Comment: You are open for SQL injection problems. Please sanitize or parameterize your query.

Comment: Don't worry, nothing bad every happened from not sanitizing a query; --DROP database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everything in life was just as easy as coding...

Figured out that using an invisible `<iframe>` as proposed in another stackoverflow thread solves the download problem as stated above.
The database is updated, the download initiated by the browser and I'm a happy little coder again :)

Thanks all for your input!

Answer (score 2):

As Barman correctly states in his comment, clicking the link not only executes your `$.post()`, but it also follows that link. Doing an alert delays following that link, so the post is executed. Otherwise it is interupted. To prevent all this from happening, make your function return `false`, so the link does not get followed:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.download', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.post("view/jquery/player.itemdload.php", { id: id });
    return false; // don't follow the link's href
});
```

But beware, now you will no longer be reloading your page. So you don't directly see the value has been incremented. Consider making your player.itemload.php return the new value, and use `ajax` in stead of `post`.

Comment: I've tidied up my code and used `ajax` instead. The PHP script returns a `json` formatted array which includes the ID number, title and download location.
I've also changed the `href` attribute of the links for downloading the files so the download count works properly.
Only problem is that now the browser won't download the files. I have to tell jQuery to fire up the download somehow. Tried `window.location(data.download)` where `data.download` contains the `json` formatted download reference.